# WPF Dispatcher ListBox.Items.Add out of order

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, listbox, dispatcher

(Excuse, I'm Japanese. So I don't know so much about English.)

I have made a twitter client software with WPF, C#. I try to make streaming home timeline with a thread. But only the method `Listbox.Items.Add` is out of order.

If I try to do this method, `Listbox.Items.Add` does nothing. I wish you to tell me the mistake in the following code.

```
private void TLStreamingReflect(OAuth oauth)
    {
        string APIURL = "https://userstream.twitter.com/1.1/user.json";
        StreamGETRequest(oauth, APIURL, "");
        trd = new Thread(threading);
        trd.Start();
    }
    public void threading()
    {
        //Mode MTA
        //endless loop
        while (true)
        {
            //this part is in order
            string result = Streamreader.ReadLine();
            DynamicJson JsonData = null;
            Status status = new Status();
            try
            {
                JsonData = DynamicJson.Parse(result);
                status = new Status();
                //Json→Status
                VarTo.VarToStatus(status, JsonData);
            }
            catch { }

            if (status.Text != null)
            {
                //↓this code is out of order
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { TimeLineAdd(status); }));
            }
        }
    }

public void TimeLineAdd(Status status)
    {

        //Abbreviation
        (this part work DockPanel molding)

        //↓ Only this code is out of order
        tweetarea.Items.Add(Listboxitem);
        // tweetarea is a ListBox object
    }
```

Thank you for looking.

Comment: Normally, when you have an error, it is useful to share the error details. Have you set the `ListBox.ItemsSource` property as well? You cannot set both the `ListBox.ItemsSource` property as well as the `ListBox.Itemss` property. If you used something like: `<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SomeCollection}" ... />`, then instead of calling `tweetarea.Items.Add(Listboxitem);`, try calling `SomeCollection.Add(Listboxitem);`.

Comment: Why do you say it is out of order? Do you mean that there is an error? Or just that your UI does not display the expected result?

Comment: Thank you for answering. And I'm sorry for not having written details codes and errors. This problem has been solved with your answers.